# Change toString format of data class

Tags: kotlin, tostring, data-class

I have list of custom object name as `Days` which 3 properties `key`,`value` and `isChecked`.
Here is List of Days as Follows:

```
    listOf(
         Days("monday","9:30",false),
         Days("Tuesday","9:30",true)
         )
```

output : `[Days(key=Monday, value=9:30 AM, isChecked=true), Days(key=Tuesday, value=9:30 AM, isChecked=true)]`

data Class:

```
data class Days(
    val key: String,
    var value: String,
    var isChecked:Boolean
)
```

Now I do not want to print the last properties of each object i,e `isChecked=true` or `isChecked=false`..How can i achieve that . I have tried `filter` and `map` lambdas but did not get desired result.

Expected o/p : `[Days(key=Monday, value=9:30 AM), Days(key=Tuesday, value=9:30 AM)]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the how the object appears when converted to a string, override the `toString()` function:

```
data class Days(
    val key: String,
    var value: String,
    var isChecked: Boolean
) {
    override fun toString(): String = "Days(key=$key, value=$value)"
}

fun main() {
    val days = listOf(
        Days("monday", "9:30", false),
        Days("Tuesday", "9:30", true)
    )

    for (item in days) println(item)
}
```

Output:

```
Days(key=monday, value=9:30)
Days(key=Tuesday, value=9:30)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write this alternate version of `toString()` yourself.

```
list.map { "Days(key=${it.key}, value=${it.value})" }
    .also { println(it) }
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks .! but this will return 'list<String>' and i want 'list<Days>'

Comment: There’s no such thing as an instance of your Days class that simply doesn’t have the property. That would have to be a completely different class.

Comment: I have `Days` as data class and list as List<Days>

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Do you just want to change what you get when a `Days` class is printed? If so, you have to override the `toString()` function.